# Spacings in TOC in a beamer presentation

Tags: latex, beamer, tableofcontents

In a LaTeX beamer presentation the spacings between the section numbers and section titles are too small for 2-digit section numbers and actually negative for 3- or 4-digit section numbers. I want the spacings in the case of 2,3,4 etc. digit section numbers to be the same as the spacings in the 1-digit case. The 1-digit case is super. I want the same for subsections and subsubsections. Is there a way to do this? (I am using texlive2023 in overleaf).

```
\documentclass[9pt,trans,xcolor={table},envcountsect]{beamer} % Plain

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usetheme[shownavsym,right]{Aalborg}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertframenavigationsymbol 
\insertsectionnavigationsymbol \insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol} % Nav symbols

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ShiftSectionNumber}[1]{%
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=\numexpr#1+\beamer@tocsectionnumber}
\makeatother

\makeatletter

\newlength{\secnumwidth}
\settowidth{\secnumwidth}{\the\beamer@sectionmax.\space}
\newlength{\subsecnumwidth}
\settowidth{\subsecnumwidth}{\the\beamer@sectionmax.1\space\space}
\newlength{\subsubsecnumwidth}
\settowidth{\subsubsecnumwidth}{\the\beamer@sectionmax.1.1}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
  \leavevmode%
  % prevents the period to be printed with the first/last section option
  \ifnum\beamer@tempcount>\beamer@toclastsection
  \else
  \ifnum\beamer@tempcount>0
    \makebox[\secnumwidth][l]{\inserttocsectionnumber.}%
  \fi\fi%
  \inserttocsection\par%
}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{%
\leavevmode\leftskip=\secnumwidth\rlap{\inserttocsectionnumber.                  
\inserttocsubsectionnumber}\hspace*{\subsecnumwidth}\inserttocsubsection\par}

\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{%
\leavevmode\leftskip=\dimexpr\subsecnumwidth+\secnumwidth\rlap{\inserttocsectionnumber.        
\inserttocsubsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsubsectionnumber}\hspace*{\subsubsecnumwidth}   
\inserttocsubsubsection\par}
\makeatother


\begin{frame}%[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Overview}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{First Section (1-digit section number)}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\ShiftSectionNumber{8}
\section{Tenth Section (2-digit section number)}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\ShiftSectionNumber{89}
\section{Hundredth Section (3-digit section number)}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\ShiftSectionNumber{899}
\section{Thousandth Section (4-digit section number)}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\begin{frame}[<+->]{Spacing in TOC}
    Hello.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make an example which reproduces the problem without your shift number hack? My code assumes that the number of sections (approximately) equals the last section number

Comment: I think it's difficult to fit in more sections than (approximately) 10 in the TOC. I need to make presentations that start with more-than-1-digit section numbers as a continuation from the last class. Thus the shift section number hack (probably found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473226/beamer-how-to-change-the-number-of-the-first-section).

Comment: You could use the `totcount` package to store the biggest section number for the next run and then use this instead of `\beamer@sectionmax`